# Whats the purpose of "this" when create object in memory? - android

Tags: android

someone can help me with this?
I didn't understand two things.
one, is that thing:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams center_ob_l = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

what is the meaning of WARP.CONTENT and why should I do this?

second thing, is the "this":

```
Button log_b = new Button(this);
```

why should i send "this" in those brackets?

and why at all I would want to create by myself the buttons and things instead of just go to the visual device and throw the things I want to the screen?

Comment: It seems you are having so many doubts with android. Try www.developer.android.com and spent more time to understand it

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for "this":
[Button btn = new Button(this); what is the use of "this" in this context....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922765/button-btn-new-buttonthis-what-is-the-use-of-this-in-this-context)

For understanding WRAP_CONTENT read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: i realize now the second thing of "what is warp_content" but still didnt undersand the "this" meaning..
i know in CPP "this" is a reference to the speciphic object im working on, but its not similar to that

Answer (score 0):

WRAP_CONTENT means that the relativelayout establish his size fitting his content.

this (java key) refers to current object, whatever it is, the current istance of the class you are coding.

if you don't need to build programmatically your layout, build it with visual editor, when you will need to create the layout programmatically you will understand it by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

LayoutParams is used to tell how the view is going to be drawn, you are using this ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int width, int height) where WRAP_CONTENT is the width and height. 
check this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

For Button log_b = new Button(this);
this keyword in java refers to the current class object.

Button(Context context) 'this' is the context you are passing in the constructor
check this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

**wrap_content**
which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)

It's roughly the equivalent of setting a Windows Form Control's Autosize property to true

**this**
 is required by the way android works with Context. Specifically when you are passing this you are basically passing the class that encapsulates this statement.